# Error ISAM instable no se pudo encontrar el archivo en wpf

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, wpf, ms-access

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicacion en wpf donde cree una base dato con acess e hice la conexion, el problema radica en que cuando corro la aplicacion para propobar la Base de dato me sale un mensaje No se pudo encontrar el archivo ISAM instable.

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            cmd.Connection = Conexion;
            cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO ID-Proyectos(Titulo-Programa,Titulo-Proyecto,Clasificacion,Prioridad,Entidad-Principal,Jefe-Proyecto,Duracion,Financiamiento,Resumen) Value('"+ Titulo_Programa.Text +"','" + Titulo_Proyecto.Text +"','" + ComboBox.Text +"','"+ ComboBox1.Text+ "', '" + EntidadPrincipal.Text + "','" + Jefe.Text + "','" + Duracion.Text + "','" + Financiamiento.Text + "','" + Resumen.Text +"' )";
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo_Programa", Titulo_Programa);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo_Proyecto", Titulo_Proyecto);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clasificacion", ComboBox);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prioridad", ComboBox1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entidad-Principal", EntidadPrincipal);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jefe-Proyecto", Jefe);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Duracion", Duracion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Financiamiento", Financiamiento);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Resumen", Resumen);
                MessageBox.Show("Guardado");
            }
        }
```

Comment: El problema no está casi seguro en el codigo que muestras, sino en la definicion de la Conexion. Muy probablemente tengas una definición errónea o incompleta.

Comment: OleDbConnection Conexion= new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Dta Source=\\GestorProyectos.accdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd= new OleDbCommand();

Comment: Esta es mi definicion de conexion

Comment: En lugar de en un comentario, es mejor que pulses [edit] y lo agreges a tu pregunta :) Yo ahora mismo no puedo mirarlo pero es posuible que otro usuario pueda ayudarte

Comment: ya amigo el problema era que  escribi mal el Data Source, pero el nuevo error radica en que nio puede encontrar la ruta de la base de dato....alguien pudiera ayudarme a como definirla

Comment: Pon la ruta completa de tu archivo en el source, aun asi tu código de tu pregunta esta mal

Answer (score 0):

Pon la ruta completa de tu bd en el source:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
> Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;

Más info [Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Y el código que pusiste deberia de ser asi:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        cmd.Connection = Conexion;

        //Estas pasando parametros USALOS
        cmd.CommandText= @"INSERT INTO ID-Proyectos(Titulo-Programa,Titulo-Proyecto,Clasificacion,Prioridad,Entidad-Principal,Jefe-Proyecto,Duracion,Financiamiento,Resumen) 
        Value(@Titulo_Programa, @Titulo_Proyecto, @Clasificacion, @Prioridad, @Entidad-Principal, @Jefe-Proyecto, @Duracion, @Financiamiento, @Resumen";
        
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo_Programa", Titulo_Programa);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo_Proyecto", Titulo_Proyecto);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clasificacion", ComboBox.Text); //Le tienes que poner .text 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prioridad", ComboBox1.Text); //Le tienes que poner .text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entidad-Principal", EntidadPrincipal);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jefe-Proyecto", Jefe);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Duracion", Duracion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Financiamiento", Financiamiento);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Resumen", Resumen);
            
         i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("Guardado");
    }
```